# Fall Recovery Assist

Tags: self-help

My father has very severe spinal issues and falls frequently. If he falls indoors, he is able to push or pull himself up from a nearby object with little to no help. Outdoors, he has nothing to pull up on and difficulties getting someone to help.

I was looking for something sturdy he could have with him to aid in picking himself up. He is too proud to use a walker of any kind as he is also still quite young.

Comment: Questions requesting medical advice are off topic here, so I'm voting to close this question, but I will say this: Never mind getting up -- the falls need to stop. Sooner or later one of those falls is going to cause significant injury such as a fractured hip or head injury, which could end his life or end his life as he knows it. So quit trying to figure out how to get him off the ground and figure out how to keep him off the ground in the first place.

Comment: @narusan "fixed language" is a terrible edit comment. Especially in this case where you removed any mention of falling, which is what the question is all about. You did a good job of removing fluff but remember to leave the question in a useful and answerable state.

Comment: @Narusan I like to be specific: are you fixing spelling, grammar, punctuation? Did you rearrange sentences? Did you remove meta talk or fluff? Your comment needs to tell reviewers why they should accept your edit and it also needs to educate the OP. When I see generic edit comments I am more likely to reject.

Answer (score 1):

Any kind of mobility aid such as a walker or cane will reduce the incidence of falls, which is probably more important than helping to get up from them. The walker will also (if the brakes are on) serve as a device to help him get up. As well, any mobility aid tells onlookers "this person has a medical condition." If he looks too young to fall down for medical reasons, people may assume he is drunk or high, and feel a reluctance to help him.

You can overcome his walker resistance by telling him it's not for him to walk with, it's for him to get back up with. This [page from the Saskatoon Health Region](https://www.saskatoonhealthregion.ca/locations_services/Services/Falls-Prevention/Pages/Tips/MobilityaidsImproveIndependence.aspx) has fall prevention tips and suggests a conversation with a doctor on what aid might be most useful. There is also [a Wikipedia page on fall prevention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_prevention) that cites studies of strength and balance training and Tai Chi, along with changing medications and glasses, as ways to reduce falls. Certainly being stronger and having good balance would also help for getting up from a fall. A person who insists they are too young for a walker might be open to some training and therapy to improve strength and balance.

Answer (score -3):

This is what we use in the ambulance service, they aren't cheap, but haven't had to lift a fallen person for many years because of this. I believe you can get some funding if you live in the U.K. But not sure about other counties. Great for people with spinal pains as you can start on it flat and slowly sit up as it raises. Your father can operate on his own but a lot easier with another person. If he struggles to "shuffle" onto the cushion then use of a "slide sheet" like EZ Slide (quite cheap) is great. We use these in conjunction every day.

https://mangarhealth.com/uk/store/product/patient-lifting/elk-lifting-cushion/

Comment: We are talking about falls outside. I don't quite see how bringing a cushion with you everything you go outside would be handy.

Comment: Depending on where it is outside, for example the mangar comes in a carry case that can fit in your car, the battery pack will inflate the cushion 2-3 times easily and will charge from a 12v adapter. As I said in the answer you would need someone else with you to retrieve it, but it's a "no lift" solution for someone who falls

Comment: Sorry, but I have to agree with @Narusan that it's just not practical. What's he supposed to do if he's home alone and wants to go out to get the mail? If he needs someone with him to operate a bulky £1,440 device, then he'd be better off simply having that someone walk with him and make sure he doesn't fall.